# Javascript failing in external file only

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Can anyone tell me why I get an error on the 2nd line saying 'unexpected string' but works fine when I have it directly on my view (i'm using MVC 3, not that it makes a difference):

```
function getUsers(processId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action('GetProcessApprovers', 'Risk')",
        data: { processId: processId },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = "<option value=\"\">-- Please select --</option>"

            if (data != "") {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                });
            }

            $("#ProcessOwnerId").html(items);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Because your `url: "@Url.Action('GetProcessApprovers', 'Risk')",` only executes in the context of the view, not in an external JS file. It's razor code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `url: "@Url.Action('GetProcessApprovers', 'Risk')"`, only executes in the context of the view, not in an external JS file. It's razor code.

You need to pass the url to the Javascript in some other way, perhaps as a parameter of your function.

```
getUsers(processId, ajaxUrl)
```

Another way would be to write out the url from the HtmlHelper into a data attribute in your view and then pick it up in your Javascript.

**HTML**

```
<div id="someContainer" data-url="@Url.Action('GetProcessApprovers', 'Risk')">...
```

**JS**

`var url = $("#someContainer").attr("data-url");`

Comment: If you go the data attribute route, it should just be `$("#someContainer").attr("data-url")`, no call to `.val()` afterwards.

Comment: tbh -if you go the data attribute way, you should take advantage of jquery's built in methd for this. so, rather than `$("#someContainer").attr("data-url")`, all you need to do is: `$("#someContainer").data("url")`. a little bit of jquery *magic* :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your url parametre is has the issue.
please change it like this:

```
 url: '@Url.Action("GetProcessApprovers", "Risk")',
```

Hope it works

Comment: That is a good point actually. Not sure if it is the only problem here, but you do need to use the double quotes on the Action parameters. Well spotted!

Comment: I usually do, I was just messing about with it trying to get it to work. ta.